# How SwiftUI sets the spacing between the underline and the text？

Tags: ios, swiftui

Code to set underline，I want to make the space between the text and the underline larger.

```
 Text("underline text")
 .underline()
```

Answer (score 9):

Underline is a font feature, you can do custom under just by drawing line anywhere needed

[image: demo]

```
var body: some View {
    HStack {
        Text("Before")
        Text("underline text")
            .overlay(
                Rectangle().frame(height: 1).offset(y: 4)
                , alignment: .bottom)
        Text("after.")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, it works for me, and the code is concise.

Comment: The only drawback of this solution is that you cannot combine the `Text`s with `+` operation because the one with `.overlay` modifier became a `View`, not a `Text` anymore.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add padding between the Text and overlay. This way you don't need to mess around with the line height and offset.

```swift
Text("Hello World")
    .padding(.bottom, 10) // <- play with distance
    .overlay(
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20, style: .continuous)
            .fill(Color.blue).frame(height: 4), // <- thickness of line
        alignment: .bottom
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

How about use a custom view instead of .underline ?

```
struct MyUnderline: View {
      let color: Color = .black
      let height: CGFloat = 1
      var body: some View {
          Rectangle()
            .fill(color)
            .frame(height: height)
      }
}
```

```
Text("underline text")
MyUnderline()
  .padding(.top, -10)
```

Comment: Yes, but requires VStack packaging

Answer (score 0):

Set baseline offset.

```
Text("text")
    .underline()
    .baselineOffset(4)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You could create a custom view that takes the text and underline padding as parameters

```
struct UnderlinedText: View {

   var text: String
   var underlinePadding: CGFloat

   var body: some View {
       VStack (spacing: underlinePadding) {
           Text(text)
           GeometryReader { proxy in
               Rectangle()
                   .frame(width: proxy.size.width, height: 1)
           }
        }
    }
}
```

And use it as follows

```
UnderlinedText(text: "Hello underlined text", underlinePadding: 10.0)
```

Comment: It is a feasible solution, but the overlay feels lighter

Comment: You can change the thickness by changing the rectangle height