# SwiftUI: Width of an underline

Tags: text, swiftui, underline

Is there any possibility to change the width of an `.underline()` in SwiftUI?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit:
Any solution where I don't loose this effect would be absolutely perfect:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63239844/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi Thank you, that would be a nice compromise solution indeed