# SwiftUI: underlined text does not work with background material

Tags: swift, xcode, text, swiftui, background

When I tried to display an underlined text with background material, I faced a problem

After some work around, I succeeded in creating the minimal test case that does not work as I expect

Could you please tell me, that is my wrong expectations, or I just missed something?

**BTW**: That works fine with other text modifiers, such as `.bold()` or `.italic()`

Here is an example to reproduce the bug:

```swift
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        LinearGradient(colors: [.orange, .yellow, .red], startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
        Text("Some underlined text")
            .underline()
            .padding()
            .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
    }
}
```

[image]

Works fine:

```swift
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        LinearGradient(colors: [.orange, .yellow, .red], startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
        Text("Some underlined text")
            .underline()
            .padding()
            .background(.white)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like a bug. This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/63239844/12299030.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        LinearGradient(colors: [.orange, .yellow, .red], startPoint:            .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
        Text("Some underlined text")
            .underline()
            .padding()
            .background(
                Rectangle() //Add this one line of code
                    .fill(.ultraThinMaterial)
            )
    }
}
```

Add this one to your code will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably looks like bug. But you can use next modifier to achieve normal behavior

```
struct Blur: UIViewRepresentable {
    var style: UIBlurEffect.Style = .systemMaterial
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIVisualEffectView {
        return UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: style))
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIVisualEffectView, context: Context) {
        uiView.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: style)
    }
}
```

Implement it to your text view

```
Text("Some underlined text")
    .underline()
    .padding()
    .background(Blur(style: .systemUltraThinMaterial))
```