# SwiftUI underline() results in broken underline

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to underline some text in a home screen widget but the underline always appears broken:

```
struct NotLoggedInSmallView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Ready to write a new chapter in travel?")
            .underline()
    }
}
```

[image: underline]

Changing font/sizae/baseline... doesn't help.

I worked around this in another places by just drawing line below the field but that doesn't handle wrapped text. Seems like pretty basic stuff but I can't seem to find a way that works.

Comment: Your posted code gives me the desired result. The problem must be somewhere else ... custom font? other font modifiers in parent view?

Comment: I am using a custom font but changing to system for gives same result

Comment: Here is another question where it's showing the same issue but changing background doesn't fix it in my case

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72582283/swiftui-underlined-text-does-not-work-with-background-material

Comment: The same code works fine when it's in an app and not an extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue.

This issue is because some characters like "p", "q", and "y".. descend below the Text's baseline.

So we need to modify the baselineOffset.

```
    extension AttributedString {
    func getUnderLinedTxt(string: String, color: Color, font: UIFont) -> AttributedString {
        var name = AttributedString(string)
        var container = AttributeContainer()
        container.foregroundColor = color
        container.underlineStyle = .single
        container.baselineOffset = font.capHeight / 2
        name.mergeAttributes(container)
        return name
    }
}
```

Here **font.capHeight** is height of capital letter present in the string.

if no capital letter present, we can use **font.descender** or **font.ascender** respectively.

**Usage**

```
    struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        let uiFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .bold)
        let swiftUIFont = Font(uiFont)


        let txt = AttributedString()
            .getUnderLinedTxt(string: "please read our Terms apply",
                              color: .black, font: uiFont)
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                Text(txt).font(swiftUIFont)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 2):

Try attributed string instead

```
var body: some View {
    Text(AttributedString("Ready to write a new chapter in travel?", 
       attributes: AttributeContainer([.underlineStyle: 1])))
}
```

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / watchOS 8.5

[image: demo]

Comment: I tried this approach but still seeing the same issue. So strange

Comment: Needed then more detailed description of test env: OS, version, target, etc. ... Maybe it is some corner case bug.